# bubble sort won't work in function

Tags: c, sorting

I try to sort a set of strings using bubble sort but for some reason it doesn't work properly. It just prints the strings. I have tried to fix it but the problem remains. What can I do?I want to sort the string alphabetically

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    int main(){
       int i,j,count;
       char str[20][50],temp[20];
       printf("How many strings u are going to enter?: ");
       scanf("%d",&count);

       printf("Enter Strings one by one: ");
       for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
          gets(str[i]);


       bubbleSort(str ,count);

       printf("Order of Sorted Strings:");
       for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
          puts(str[i]);

       return 0;
    }

    void bubbleSort(char *str[], int count){
 int i, j;

 for(i = 1; i < count; i++){
    for(j = 1; j < count; j++){
        if (strcmp(str[j - 1], str[j]) > 0) {
            swap(str[j], str[j-1]);
        }
    }
}


 return;
}
void swap(char *x, char *y){
    char temp[20];
  strcpy(temp, x);
  strcpy(x, y);
  strcpy(y, temp);

 return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `str[j-1] > str[j]` doesn't do a comparison of the string values. It's doing a comparison of the memory address of the string values. Since everything is in an array in continuous memory, the address `str[j-1]` will always be less than the address `str[j]` and nothing will ever be swapped.

You need to do your comparison in the values of the strings using `strcmp`.

Comment: so should I do it without using the swap function?

Comment: No you still need a to swap. You just need to compare the values of the strings not the pointers.

Comment: i edited my code...am i close?

Comment: Now in your swap function, in `strcpy` x and y are already pointers no need to deference them. Also when you pass the strings into your swap function `str[j]` and `str[j-1]` already pointers to the string so you should call swap as just `swap(str[j], str[j-1])`.

Comment: i did what you said but after i type the strings the program crashes

Comment: If you run in a debugger, it will show you the exact line that is causes the crash.